# make (array of) actionlistener(s) change value

Tags: java, for-loop, actionlistener

So I need to get the "i" out of this loop put into a variable outside of this loop (I want this to happen when a button is clicked) using an action-listener... 
Any idea how to to this?

```
ArrayList<Kaart> Thand=uno.gethSpeler().getHand();
for(int i=0;i<Thand.size();i++){
  btnArr[i].setIcon(Thand.get(i).getImg());
  btnArr[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      iKaart=i;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "put into a variable outside of this loop"? It's not really clear what you mean. I'll *try* to answer it, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want this - just creating a `final` variable within the loop, taking its value from `i`, so that you can refer to it in your anonymous inner class:

```
ArrayList<Kaart> thand = uno.gethSpeler().getHand();

for(int i=0; i < thand.size(); i++) {
  final int copy = i;
  btnArr[i].setIcon(thand.get(i).getImg());

  btnArr[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      iKaart = copy;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Or the listener could be a non anonymous inner class taking the index as a constructor argument.